# Al instalar mi aplicacion android me aparecen permisos que no estan en el manifest

Tags: android, permisos

Ya revisé bien cada línea del manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />



    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "disruptiva.com.llegueconductor"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 31
        versionName '2.1.1'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}



repositories {
    maven { url "://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/http-core-4.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.2'
    compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
}
```

Y tengo estos permisos en la aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />



    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

Comment: Pero cual es el problema? como sabes que hay permisos que no estan en el AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: porque entro en ajustes y allí veo en la información de la aplicacion

Comment: ahhhhh ahora entiendo, puedes agregar una imagen de lo que ves en ajustes y agrego una respuesta.

Comment: Podrías agregar todo tu AndroidManifest.xml por favor? una pregunta esta aplicación la descargas de la PlayStore?

Comment: depende tambien de los plugins que uses, al compilar se hace un merge de los AndroidManifests.xml

Comment: estás usando librerías de terceros me imagino

Comment: Añade tu gradle (app), puede que estes usando un alguna librería que lo este ocupando como bien lo dice @Chisko

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que las librerias que utilizó tienen algunos permisos en sus manifest entonces cuando se compila la aplicacion se genera un solo manifest de todo con el nuevo merged Manifest de android studio pude solucionarlo el agrega esto al manifest por cada uno que deseo quitar

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"
    tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: esta es la respuesta correcta

Answer (score 0):

1) `android.permission.CALL_PHONE`

Permite hacer llamadas telefónicas (por eso tienes los contactos) sin la necesidad de pasar a través de la interfaz de usuario. (Grado de complejidad PELIGROSO)

2) `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`

Permite que una aplicación acceda a una localización precisa.

3) `com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.RE‌​AD_GSERVICES`

Este permiso esta MUY MUY MUY poco documentado, de hecho en la lista de permisos de Android no aparece. Es muy probable que este permiso haga aparecer algunos que tu no estas dejando explicitamente en tu manifiesto.

Answer (score 0):

Los permisos que aparecen en tu imagen, aparecen en tu aplicación si estan definidos en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`, por orden:

1)

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

2)

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

3)

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

4)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los que no veo en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` son `READ_CONTACTS` y `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, es un poco raro no se muestren, son 2 causas, el permiso puede estar definido en otra parte del AndroidManifest.xml o estas viendo una versión de la aplicación que fue generada con los permisos.

Comment: ya revise todo el manifest y no estan en ninguna parte y esa version la acabe de instalar en blanco (desinstale la versión vieja e instale esta nueva)

Answer (score 0):

Investigando un poco por [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618806/is-read-gservices-permission-still-required-for-google-maps) el causante puede ser la versión de las google play services 8 que añade el permiso de `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Si actualizas la nueva versión 10 de las google play services, sus permisos.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

La nueva versión no necesita `com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES`

Comment: ok voy a intentar solo no se si tenga problemas de compatibilidad ya que llevo bastante utilizando la 8